# how to express alternative flows in activity diagram

Tags: uml, diagrams, modeling, activity

I want to express the below events in an activity diagram:

- An alternative flow, such as "at step x of basic flow, user clicks cancel instead of ok".
- An alternative entry to the use case, such as "instead of click the bold button, use can press Ctrl-B".
- An error, such as "when user clicks save, the system is unable to save the file to disk."

How can I do these?

Thank you.

Comment: activity diagram  focus on control flow of system .why you want to display error in activity diagram?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need something called constraints or guardian conditions.[image]

see where it says [loopguard] in that diagram?  you can put [if user does x] implying the next state won't occur until the condition is true.

for the second question, I'd just write "user presses ctrl+B or selects Bold" in the same state circle or as a note to the side.

for the third question, you can use exceptions.  It looks like this:
[image]

Comment: IMO you make several mistake here:1) you use concurrent node instead of decision node. 2) This is an Activity diagram, not a State Machine, so in your boxes, you should have "first Action" or "first Activity" instead of "first State".

Answer (score 5):

I'm not an expert on diagramming, but I like using shapes with multiple points to specify an alternative path, such as Diamonds or Triangles

[image]